# CSS File Not Updating on Deploy (Google AppEngine)

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, google-cloud-platform

I pushed a new version of my website, but now the CSS and static images are not deploying properly.

Here is the messed up page: http://www.gaiagps.com

Appengine shows the latest version as being correct though: http://1.latest.gaiagps.appspot.com/

Any help?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've seen this before on App Engine, even when using cache-busting query parameters like `/stylesheets/default.css?{{ App.Version }}`.

Here's my (unconfirmed) theory:

1. You push a new version by deploying or changing a new version to `default`.
2. While this update is being propagated to all GAE instances running your app...
3. ...someone hits your site.
4. The request for static resource `default.css{{ App.Version }}` is sent to Google's CDN, which doesn't yet have it.
5. Google's CDN asks GAE for the resource before propagation from step #2 is done for all instances.
6. If you're unlucky, GAE serves up the resource from an instance running the old version...
7. ...which now gets cached in Google's CDN as the authoritative "new" version.

When this (if this is what happens) happens, I can confirm that no amount of cache-busting browser work will help. The Google CDN servers are holding the wrong version.

**To fix:** The only way I've found to fix this is to deploy another version. You don't run the risk of this happening again (if you haven't made any CSS changes since the race condition), because even if the race condition occurs, presumably your first update is done by the time you deploy your second one, so all instances will be serving the correct version no matter what.

Comment: I'll buy this... though I'm not sure it's right. It eventually just cleared itself up hours later.

Comment: I am encountering it now. I've deployed many, many times but it keeps serving the outdated static files. However if I reference the version of the app - eg, alpha5.latest.xxx.appspot.com - then the correct file is served.

Comment: I've encountered this problem a few times. For whatever reason, this is the fixed. I think it's something to do with upstream caching from the google instance web host. If you see the problem and request the css file directly in a browser with the querystring, then the issue goes away. It looks like the caching is invalidated the first time a request is made with a unique url to a static file.

Comment: Easy and quick solution, I also use date instead  of "App.version" ie. foo.css?05022015 where the date when the css was changed.

Comment: What about you serve an static file for your domain index? This problem still happen and cannot be solved with a cache buster

Comment: I also was encountering this and the only solution I could find was to deploy to a new bucket. To do this, go to https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser and create a new bucket, then redeploy using `gcloud app deploy --bucket gs://your-new-bucket`. This uploaded all the files again and created a new version in App Engine

Answer (score 3):

Following is what has worked for me.

1. Serve your css file from the static domain. This is automatically created by GAE.

   //static.{your-app-id}.appspot.com/{css-file-path}
2. Deploy your application. At this point your app will be broken.
3. change the version of the css file

   //static.{your-app-id}.appspot.com/{css-file-path}?v={version-Name}
4. deploy again.

Every time you change the css file. you will have to repeat 2,3 and 4.

Answer (score 2):

Your link looks fine to me, unless I'm missing something.

You may have cached your old CSS, and not getting the new CSS after updating it.  Try clearing your browser cache and see if that works.

Going to 1.latest downloads the new CSS since it's not in your cache, so it appears correctly to you.

Comment: The menu at the bottom of the menu is not horizontal or big enough, and the images in the slideshow are wrong. I have tried refreshing my cache and loading from a different browser too.

Comment: The two sites you linked look exactly the same on Firefox and Chrome for OS X. I suspect there's still some issue that's only affecting you, or your browser, unless someone else can verify that it looks different.

Comment: Try using <Shift>+<F5> to force reload your page (at least in FF). Here everything seems fine, both menu and slideshow images. Good luck.

Comment: The problem was server-side caching as it turns out. App Engine is weird.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem as well.  I was using flask with GAE so I didn't have a static handler in my `app.yaml`.  When I added it, the deploy works.  Try adding something like this

```
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```

to your `app.yaml` and deploy again.  It worked for me.  Apparently Google is trying to optimize by not updating files that it thinks users can't see.

Answer (score 2):

As found by **shoresh**, the docs for the standard environment for Pyhton state that both settings for [static cache expiration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#static_cache_expiration), the individual element `expiration` and the top-level element `default_expiration`, are responsible for defining "the expiration time [that] will be sent in the `Cache-Control` and `Expires` HTTP response headers". This means that "files are likely to be cached by the user's browser, as well as by intermediate caching proxy servers such as Internet Service Providers".

The problem here is that "re-deploying a new version of the app will **not** reset any caches". So if one has set `default_expiration` to, e.g., 15 days, but makes a change to a CSS or JS file and re-deploy the app, there is no guarantee that those files will be automatically served due to active caches, particularly due to intermediate caching proxy servers, which may include Google Cloud servers - what seems to be the case since accessing your-project-name.appspot.com also serves outdated files.

The same documentation linked above states that "if you ever plan to modify a static file, it should have a short (less than one hour) expiration time. In most cases, the default 10-minute expiration time is appropriate". That is something one should think about *before* setting any static cache expiration. But for those who, like myself, **didn't know all of this beforehand** and have already been caught by this problem, I've found a solution.

Even though the documentation states that it's not possible to clear those intermediate caching proxies, one can delete at least the Google Cloud cache.

**In order to do so**, head to your [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) and open your project. Under the left hamburger menu, head to Storage -> Browser. There you should find at least one Bucket: your-project-name.appspot.com. Under the Lifecycle column, click on the link with respect to your-project-name.appspot.com. Delete any existing rules, since they may conflict with the one you will create now.

Create a new rule by clicking on the 'Add rule' button. For the object conditions, choose **only** the 'Newer version' option and set it to 1. Don't forget to click on the 'Continue' button. For the action, select 'Delete' and click on the 'Continue' button. Save your new rule.

This newly created rule will take up to 24 hours to take effect, but at least for my project it took only a few minutes. Once it is up and running, the version of the files being served by your app under your-project-name.appspot.com **will always be the latest deployed**, solving the problem. Also, if you are routinely editing your static files, you should remove the `default_expiration` element from the app.yaml file, which will help avoid unintended caching by other servers.

Comment: This answer +1 formed the basis for the solution that finally worked for me which is fully documented here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69781887/1205871

Answer (score 1):

Ok For newer people seeing this problem i tried the cache-bursting approach and seem to have fixed it here is an example of what i did  for the css import on app.cfg file create a variable to hold your appid as set in app.yaml file and set it as one below

```
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='file.css') }}?{{config.APP_ID}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Also for the app.yaml file add this config to be on the safe side

handlers:

- url: /static
  static_dir: static

Answer (score 0):

Here whats worked for me:

First, I've changed the *version* on **app.yaml**.

**Then follow these steps below**

Go to your console -> Click on your Project.

On the side menu, click on **Computation** -> **Versions**:

There it will be all versions, and which version is default. Mine was set to an older version.

Mark the new version.

For me worked. Any concerns?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for the standard environment for Pyhton: [static_cache_expiration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#static_cache_expiration).

> After a file is transmitted with a given expiration time, there is
>   generally no way to clear it out of intermediate caches, even if the
>   user clears their own browser cache. Re-deploying a new version of the
>   app will not reset any caches. Therefore, if you ever plan to modify a
>   static file, it should have a short (less than one hour) expiration
>   time. In most cases, the default 10-minute expiration time is
>   appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

For new people coming to this old questions/set of answers I wanted to give an updated answer. I think in 2018-19 the following information will probably fix most of the CSS update issues people are having:

Make sure your `app.yaml` has the following:

```
 handlers:
   - url: /static
     static_dir: static
```

- Run `gcloud app deploy`
- Chill for 10 minutes.. and the shift-reload your website

This approach is suggested by google as well (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/serving-static-files).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add wildcard at the end of the url and service setup on **dispatch.yaml** file.

Example:

```
dispatch:
  - url: "example.com/*"
    service: default

  - url: "sub.example.com/*"
    service: subexample
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use 2020 GCP App Engine, just add `default_expiration` to your app.yaml file and set it to `1m`.

```
default_expiration: "1m"
```

More info: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref/#runtime_and_app_elements

Comment: Just be aware that if you have had deployed a static file before, App Engine will still serve the old file, even if the `default_expiration` is set. A workaround for this is to rename the file.

Answer (score -1):

Try clearing cache on your browser. Had exact same issue and got it fixed by simply clearing cache.