# Google App Engine Jinja2 - Templates not updating

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I've been having trouble with my templates not updating in the Google App Engine Dev Python Server. If I leave the server running for a while, my templates will not update in the browser after I change them. My best guess is that jinja2 is caching these templates some how?

I'm rendering my templates using the following code:

```
_jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
    loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(root_dir))

def write_template(self, template_name, template_data = {}):
    template = _jinja_environment.get_template(template_name)
    self.response.out.write(template.render(template_data))
```

I've tried restarting my app engine application, as well as undeploying and re-deploying, but the templates still don't update.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try any of the following

1. Clearing browser cache,
2. Renaming the template dir,
3. Changing the version

It none of them could fix it, then I dont know what is causing the problem.

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783082/css-file-not-updating-on-deploy-google-appengine)  is a similar question although the trouble happened after deploying.

Comment: I tried clearing the browser cache and changing the app engine application version. If I create a new template file, I can see the changes. However, I don't want to be changing the template names whenever I need to make changes.

Comment: Am not sure about the cure dude. If somehow you find out what is causing the problem do not forget to post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- Go to the admin console. On local machine it's: "http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/datastore"
- select the appropriate entity kind and then click on `List Entities`
- click on `Flush Memcache`

Then try reloading the app.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same issue. I have one .py file and one .html file. I tried to edit a textarea to output some text in it, but it wasn't refreshed in the browser correctly. Still the old HTML file was displayed. After I restarted the app engine it worked just fine.

So I did it again and still the same problem. But if you edit the .py file and save it, the HTML file is reloaded into app engine. I don't know why, but I think deleting a character and undo it + save is faster than always restarting the whole app.

Maybe it helps!