# App Engine: Static Files Not Updating on Deploy

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, google-cloud-platform

I pushed an HTML static file containing an Angular SPA as catch-all handler for my custom domain with this settings:

```
- url: /(api|activate|associate|c|close_fb|combine|import|password|sitemap)($|/.*)
  script: gae.php

- url: /.*
  static_files: public/static/app/v248/es/app.html
  upload: public/static/app/v248/es/app.html
  expiration: "1h"
```

That worked fine, but if I push a new app.html it doesn't update. I've tried to change the local path, deploy a new app version, even replacing the catch-all handler with a custom php endpoint, but it doesn't work, the response still is the first version of app.html I uploaded.

Other people has had the same problem ([CSS File Not Updating on Deploy (Google AppEngine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783082/css-file-not-updating-on-deploy-google-appengine)), and it looks like is related to Google CDN cache but, as far as I know, there isn't any way to flush it.

Comment: Are you sure it is Google's CDN caching and not your web browser?

Comment: 100% percent sure, it's the first thing I tried

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When performing changes in static files in an App Engine application, changes will not be available immediately, due to [cache](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#static_cache_expiration), as you already imagined. The cache in Google Cloud cannot be manually flushed, so instead I would recommend you to change the expiration time to a shorter period (by default it is 10 minutes) if you want to test how it works, and later setting an appropriate expiration time according to your requirements.

Bear in mind that you can change the static cache expiration time both [for all static files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#default_expiration) or for just [the ones you choose](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_expiration), just by setting the proper element in the *app.yaml* file.

Comment: Exactly, but even changing expiration time on already cached files won't affect them until they expire. As you point, there is no way to flush Google Edge Cache.

Comment: That's it, you are right. I can only recommend you to lower the expiration times for testing purposes, as commented earlier, and then set more appropriate values again.

Answer (score 16):

There is a way to flush static files cached by your app on Google Cloud.

Head to your [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) and open your project. Under the left hamburger menu, head to Storage -> Cloud Storage -> Browser. There you should find at least one Bucket: your-project-name.appspot.com. Under the Lifecycle column, click on the link with respect to your-project-name.appspot.com. Delete any existing rules, since they may conflict with the one you will create now.

Create a new rule by clicking on the 'Add A Rule' button. For the action, select "Set storage to nearline". For the object conditions, choose **only** the 'Number of newer versions' option and set it to 1. Click on the 'Continue' button and then click 'Create'.

This new rule will take up to 24 hours to take effect, but at least for my project it took only a few minutes. Once it is up and running, the version of the files being served by your app under your-project-name.appspot.com **will always be the latest deployed**, solving the problem. Also, if you are routinely editing your static files, you should remove any `expiration` element from handlers related to those static files and the `default_expiration` element from the app.yaml file, which will help avoid unintended caching by other servers.

Comment: This description might be old; I don't see any "Newer version" option.

Comment: I no longer use GCP, but I went there to check what has changed since I posted this answer. Actually, not much. 1) Under the left hamburger menu, head to Storage -> Cloud Storage -> Browser. 2) Go to the Lifecycle rules as instructed in the answer. 3) Keep the "Set storage class to Nearline" action selected. 4) For the object conditions, choose only the "Number of newer versions" option and set it to 1. That's it.

Comment: This answer +1 formed the basis for the solution which finally worked for me which is documented here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69781887/1205871 - which essentially goes into more detail on this approach

Answer (score 2):

**2020 Update:**

For my application I found that App Engine started failing to detect my latest app deployments once I reached `50 Versions` in my Versions list.

See (Burger Menu) -> App Engine -> Versions

After deleting a bunch of old versions on next deploy it picked up my latest changes immediately.  Not sure if this is specific to my account or billing settings but that solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had my static files over a service in Google Cloud Platform. My problem was that I didn't execute

```
gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml
```

Once executed, everything was fine. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Another problem that could be causing this is caching in Google's frontend, which depends on the cache header returned by your application. In my case, I opened Firefox's inspector on the Network tab, and saw that the stale file had a cache-control setting of 43200 seconds, i.e. 12 hours:

[image: screenshot from inspector tab]

This was for a file returned from Flask, so I fixed this by explicitly specifying max-age in the Flask response from my GAE code:

```py
return flask.send_from_directory(directory, filename, max_age=600)
```

This causes intermediate caches such as Google's frontend to only cache the file for a period of 600 seconds (10 minutes).

Unfortunately, once a file has been caches there is no way to flush it, so you will have to wait out the 12 hours. But it will solve the problem for the next time.