# App Engine Instances kept alive after new version installation

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Every time I upload a new version of my app engine, the old version automatically stops. But in one of my projects, there is a bug, and every time I upload a new versions, it does not kill the older version. This bug result in me paying for 16 different running instances last month because we had a lot of new versions:

[image]

How can I make sure it never happen again?

Answer (score 1):

[gcloud app deploy does not remove previous versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43430383/gcloud-app-deploy-does-not-remove-previous-versions)

tl;dr: Use the --version flag when deploying to specify a version name. An existing instance with the same version will be replaced then next time you deploy.

Comment: Replacing the version doesn't seem like a good idea. To avoid downtime, you want to create a new version, redirect traffic to it, then bring down the old version. That's what happens by default when you run `gcloud app deploy` without `--version`, as far as I know.