# "gcloud app deploy" does not override the static folder

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Im trying to upload to my server a static file that contains photos from a previous version which has been overwritten since then (same name, different image). I think the upload skips these files, how can I make it go over these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the deployment verbosity using the `--verbosity` option for `gcloud app deploy` and you'll see exactly which files are skipped and which aren't (you may need to modify them again since you already attempted to deploy the most recent versions).

But it could very well be a caching issue, see [App Engine: Static Files Not Updating on Deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33223616/app-engine-static-files-not-updating-on-deploy?rq=1).