# GAE flexible static files not updating after hours

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, browser-cache, cache-control, app-engine-flexible

I've been using GAE flex for a couple years now, and am stumped by my app not serving updated static files hours after deployment.

- I haven't change any default caching of static files (which I believe is 10 minutes)
- I've redeployed my app several times to new versions in case it was a one-off weird thing
- I deleted all the contents of the staging bucket and redeployed
- In Chrome, I'm reloading the file with "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" but still see the old file

Any idea what could be the problem or how to fix it?

UPDATE:

Very odd:

- Static files are updated if accessed from https://my-app.appspot.com
- But not updated from https://www.my-domain.com

Another weird difference is how the static files are presented in the Chrome window.  With `my-app.appspot.com`, the text is line-wrapped.  With `www.my-domain.com`, the text is not line-wrapped.

Comment: Looks like other people have had this issue.  See comments to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4838346/136598).  Though the answer doesn't provide a solution since deploying a new version doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Almost 24 hours later, the static files have been updated so it sorted itself out eventually.

The cached files from

- https://my-app.appspot.com
- https://www.my-domain.com

are still different in that one is line wrapped and one is not.

Would be very helpful if someone could explain why the static files are cached in different ways depending on the URL used to access them.

Comment: Can you share your app.yaml file in order to check where the issue could be?

Comment: @NibrassHaider, this should be a comment to the question and not this answer.  Given that static files work fine from the appspot.com domain, how would the app.yaml file be helpful here?

Comment: I wanted to look at app.yaml file to know whether you set default_expiration time or not.